# Prevent JOptionPane from being "closed" by clicking anywhere else

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'm currently programming a little Java game and I use the `JOptionPane` class to alert the user if an `IOException` is thrown. I'd like to know how to prevent the option pane from being "closed" by clicking anywhere else, e.g. on the desktop, because it actually doesn't end the Java process.

Comment: Huh? Clicking elsewhere does not close a dialog.

Comment: Clicking anywhere else brings that window to the front and gives it focus.  The JOptionPane is still present, just hidden behind the front window.  This is operating system  behavior, and there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @SLaks https://youtu.be/SM4TGU3NcHo

Comment: Uh, thanks @GilbertLeBlanc but how do I find the JOptionPane to close it then?

Comment: To find the JOptionPane, close every other open window.

Comment: or just minimize them, or look in Alt+Tab.

Comment: Even when I close everything, the JOptionPane isn't visible anywhere. But still thanks.

Comment: Does the option pane have a 'parent/owner'? Never mind.. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). That will answer my question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have you window always visible (regardless of the other windows) there is an option called `alwaysOnTop`, when you set that to true, the host OS will try to honour that directive displaying the window always.

Try to see if these posts helps:

- [JOptionPane displays behind the parent JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598913/joptionpane-displays-behind-the-parent-jframe)
- [how to show JOptionPane on the top of all windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880981/how-to-show-joptionpane-on-the-top-of-all-windows)